# Simple If statement for Javascript(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am trying to wrap my head around if statements. I am new to this.

I have a pretty simple script pulling data(text) from a html5 data attribute.

```
var $datatext = $(this).data('explain');
```

Now I want an if statement when html5 attribute data-explain is missing or empty.

```
var $success = if ($datatext < 0) {
    // show some other text, maybe? =
    $(this).text('Fail');
} else {
    // show original, maybe? =
    $(this).text($datatext);
}
```

Again, hard time wrapping my head around it. Ohhh these ifs.

Comment: What's the `var $success` bit for...?

Comment: My attempt to tell you guys that I, if possible, want to have it in a variable. If that is how it works.

Comment: You want to have _what_ "in a variable"? The if statement? A unicorn? What?!

Comment: I want the result of the if argument. That might sound strange for you, but I am struggling with understanding the concept. This is what I do later;
<code>$('<div />').appendTo(options.targetDiv).html('<p>' + $datatext + '</p>');</code>

Comment: There is no such result, so you must define your requirements in more abstract terms. Did you want `$success` to be populated by `true` or `false` depending on which conditional block was executed? That breaks when you introduce `elseif`. Perhaps populate `$success` independently of the `if` statement, using the same boolean condition.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit : After some trail and error I now understand that the ifelse argument is the output. What I want then is something like : if () { var success = text } else { var fail = text }

Variables inside ifelse arguments (I will try this right now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work:

```
if (typeof $datatext !== 'undefined' && $datatext.length > 0) {
     $(this).text($datatext);
} else {
     $(this).text('Fail');
}
```

Comment: `JQuery` will return an empty string if the variable is `undefined` so no need for the first check.

Comment: I tried this, and, as I am new to this, I dont understand how to implement it.
I want to be able to call the result of the if statement later, if that makes sense.

Comment: This works! Thanks! Console confirms that I am getting it right.

Though my output is still associated with $datatext (returning undefined), how do I associate it with the result from this?

Comment: My lack of knowledge restrained my vision from seeing the bigger picture. Ifelse is the output. Everything now works. My code looks messy though, but somehow I will clean it up. Thanks for possibly finally making me through my mental block.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/Bsefk/)**

```
$('.someclass').each(function() {    

    if(typeof this.attributes['data-explain']  != 'undefined')
    {
        alert(this.id + ": explain exists");
        explain = $.trim(this.getAttribute('data-explain'))
        if(explain.length > 0)
            alert(explain);
        else
            alert("no value for explain");
    }
    else
        alert(this.id + ": explain does not exists");
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

check for the length not for the data in `$datatext` rewrite your code like this

```
if ($datatext.length > 0) {
    // show original, maybe? =
    $(this).text($datatext);

} else {
    // show some other text, maybe? =
    $(this).text('Fail');
}
```